# Pick certain commits into a single commit?

Tags: git

I run into this scenario a lot where my git log becomes a mess with hundreds of commits.

```
commit d: add sky to scenery
commit c: add Christina to characters
commit b: add flowers to scenery
commit a: add Andrew to characters
```

How would something like this where `commit f = b + d`?

```
commit f: add scenery
commit e: add characters
```

Comment: you could cherry-pick b and d and then squash them into a single commit after that, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite normal for a project to acquire a lot of commits over time:-)

If you're sure you want to meld them together I see two possibilities:

1. Meld together the latest commits from your current branch using interactive [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

   ```
   git rebase --interactive HEAD~10
   ```

   Opens an editor showing the last 10 commits. Replace `pick` by `squash` (appending commit message) or `fixup` (discarding commit message). By moving the lines you can select which commits to meld together. Changing the order might cause merge conflicts, though.

   The editor will represent the current history at first:

   ```
   pick ... older commits
   pick aaaaaaa add Andrew to characters
   pick bbbbbbb add flowers to scenery
   pick ccccccc add Christina to characters
   pick ddddddd add sky to scenery
   ```

   Change it to your likes, e.g.:

   ```
   pick ... older commits (left untouched)
   reword aaaaaaa keep message, open editor to edit
   squash bbbbbbb append message to aaaaaaa
   fixup  ccccccc discard message
   fixup  ddddddd discard message
   ```
2. Meld together commits from other (remote) branches.

   For commits that are not yet part of your current branch, cherry-picking their changes and creating a new commit with all of them might be the best approach. Use [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) for this:

   ```
   git cherry-pick --no-commit $commit1
   git cherry-pick --no-commit $commit2
   ...
   git commit -m "new commit message"
   ```

**In both cases you create new commits with different SHA1 values!** Always be careful when editing history and try to avoid it for published/shared repositories.